# How to save tokens between apis without statement?

Tags: c#, .net, api, jwt

We're thinking about an architecture for our next app and we're having problems with pass the tokens between apis. We'll have:

- Front -->(call to) own login api (if all is ok we create an own token, named ownToken) -->(call to) third party api --> returns a JWT token (named 1token) -->

After everything is ok :

- Front --> User do some tasks-->(With ownToken Call to) own business api (If ownToken is ok, do some stuffs)-->  (with the 1token Call to) third party api (return some stuffs) --> Show information to the user.

We want to avoid calling the third party api every time that we want information from that api, but also we don't want to show that JWT to the user (I mean localstorage,sessionstorage...).

For more information, we'll use c# language and sql server as database.

Our question:

How do you mantain 1token between APIs?

Comment: "We want to avoid calling the third party api every time that we want information from that api"...perhaps you can cache the data, if it doesn't change often, or copy it to your own database. It's unclear how this is really related to "How do you mantain 1token between APIs?" though? Normally access tokens expire after a period, so you can store it, maybe in your DB, until it expires, but also you normally should get a refresh token from the other API which you can use for much longer, to get new access tokens. Or maybe it supports a flow with client secret so no re-authentication is needed

Comment: I can't quite work out exactly what you're worried about, but if you're hoping that the user can call the 3rd party API directly from the front application (I guess it's a browser or app?) so that the data doesn't pass through your server each time then the 3rd party API must be able to trust the front app. So either the user must authenticate directly with that API themselves, or you have to trust the app with a token you've generated on the server - as you rightly point out that could be risky. Perhaps you can clarify precisely what your concerns are around your data and tokens?

Comment: First at all thanks for answering. @ADyson is not possible to cache that information, the relation is that we need 1token to get info in every call from third party api. Yep store in a DB is the first option that cames to our minds but we would like to know if there is another options. The issue is that we don't want to any people get access that 1token from our app.

Comment: Well if you secure your database and server correctly there should be no danger of that. However and wherever you store the token during its lifetime you need to secure it. A database is a pretty reasonable choice since most databases have quite good security features, and your API, if it's the only application with direct access to the DB, can help as well. If you stored the token in a file you'd have to control access to the file instead. You could store it in the session in memory, if your API is not completely stateless, and the session lasts long enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two different things which need to be managed:

1. JWT-secured calls between your front-end and your back-end
2. JWT-secured calls between your back-end and a 3rd party.

What I would do is simply generate a 'sessionId' in the back-end which is part of the token you send to your front end.  this could be an int or guid or whatever.

I would then associate this 'sessionId' with the token retrieved from the 3rd party and store that somehow - some form of database or file storage (DB would be the obvious thing to use).

That way whenever a request comes in from your front end in your back-end code you should:

1. Extract sessionId from the token they provide
2. lookup the entry for this Id in your database to get the token associated with it
3. use this token to make whatever calls are required and respond

You'd have to make sure to update this association whenever you need to get new tokens, but that shouldn't be too hard.

You could also use this to make the nature of the thing a bit more async - you could return immediately to *your* front end with a response suggesting it's 'Working On It' then the front end could call a separate endpoint later to get the results...  That way if the 3rd party link takes a while then the original request isn't left waiting too long for a response...

Comment: Thx for answering, the first point isn't a JWT is something similar to , like you said,t a sessionId. Yep that was our thinking but we would like if there is another way to do it, but it doesn't seem. I think we'll save that sessionId relation with the JWT in sql table.. Another question, we heard that Redis is too fast to relation this kind of data... Would you use as database Redis (sessions) and SQL Server(data) or only SQL Server(sessions&data)?

Comment: I assumed JWT, but the principle is the same... There are only 2 ways to do this - either you send everything you need to the client (possibly encrypted) so that it can pass all that back on each request, or you need to keep a record of which of your tokens is associated with which of the 3rd party tokens.  As to how/where you store this (e.g. Redis Vs MsSqlServer) that depends entirely on the architecture of your system and is really too broad for an SO question.  Out of context, for this specific issue you could use either and it would probably work fine.